# Pandas index datetime formatting is not giving desired output Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried the following:

```
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y.%m.%d %HH:%MM:%SS")
df.tail()
```

The output was:

```
                    open    high    low close
Time                    
2018-07-24 16:25:00 1.16963 1.16976 1.16952 1.16952
2018-07-24 16:26:00 1.16952 1.16952 1.16938 1.16939
2018-07-24 16:27:00 1.16939 1.16940 1.16896 1.16908
2018-07-24 16:28:00 1.16909 1.16929 1.16908 1.16929
2018-07-24 16:29:00 1.16930 1.16932 1.16919 1.16925
```

I was expecting that the `Time` index of the dataframe shoud be in the format as shown in the following output:

```
                    open    high    low close
Time                    
2018.07.24 16:25:00 1.16963 1.16976 1.16952 1.16952
2018.07.24 16:26:00 1.16952 1.16952 1.16938 1.16939
2018.07.24 16:27:00 1.16939 1.16940 1.16896 1.16908
2018.07.24 16:28:00 1.16909 1.16929 1.16908 1.16929
2018.07.24 16:29:00 1.16930 1.16932 1.16919 1.16925
```

Kindly, help me get through this.

Comment: Did you try df.set_index('Time',inplace=True), which will set Time as the index?

Comment: The `Time` column itself is  indexed already I am just trying to format it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need only one `H`, `M` and `S`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['2018.07.24 16:25:00', '2018.07.24 16:26:00', '2018.07.24 16:27:00', '2018.07.24 16:28:00', '2018.07.24 16:29:00'], 'open': [1.16963, 1.1695200000000001, 1.16939, 1.16909, 1.1693], 'high': [1.1697600000000001, 1.1695200000000001, 1.1694, 1.16929, 1.1693200000000001], 'low': [1.1695200000000001, 1.1693799999999999, 1.16896, 1.16908, 1.16919], 'close': [1.1695200000000001, 1.16939, 1.16908, 1.16929, 1.16925]}).set_index('Time')
```

---

```
print (df)
                        open     high      low    close
Time                                                   
2018.07.24 16:25:00  1.16963  1.16976  1.16952  1.16952
2018.07.24 16:26:00  1.16952  1.16952  1.16938  1.16939
2018.07.24 16:27:00  1.16939  1.16940  1.16896  1.16908
2018.07.24 16:28:00  1.16909  1.16929  1.16908  1.16929
2018.07.24 16:29:00  1.16930  1.16932  1.16919  1.16925

print (df.index)
Index(['2018.07.24 16:25:00', '2018.07.24 16:26:00', '2018.07.24 16:27:00',
       '2018.07.24 16:28:00', '2018.07.24 16:29:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Time')
```

If want create `Datetimeindex`:

```
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

print (df)
                        open     high      low    close
Time                                                   
2018-07-24 16:25:00  1.16963  1.16976  1.16952  1.16952
2018-07-24 16:26:00  1.16952  1.16952  1.16938  1.16939
2018-07-24 16:27:00  1.16939  1.16940  1.16896  1.16908
2018-07-24 16:28:00  1.16909  1.16929  1.16908  1.16929
2018-07-24 16:29:00  1.16930  1.16932  1.16919  1.16925

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-24 16:25:00', '2018-07-24 16:26:00',
               '2018-07-24 16:27:00', '2018-07-24 16:28:00',
               '2018-07-24 16:29:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', freq=None)
```

But if want custom format of index, use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), but `DatetimeIndex` is lost, indices are strings:

```
df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

print (df)
                        open     high      low    close
2018.07.24 16:25:00  1.16963  1.16976  1.16952  1.16952
2018.07.24 16:26:00  1.16952  1.16952  1.16938  1.16939
2018.07.24 16:27:00  1.16939  1.16940  1.16896  1.16908
2018.07.24 16:28:00  1.16909  1.16929  1.16908  1.16929
2018.07.24 16:29:00  1.16930  1.16932  1.16919  1.16925

print (df.index)
Index(['2018.07.24 16:25:00', '2018.07.24 16:26:00', '2018.07.24 16:27:00',
       '2018.07.24 16:28:00', '2018.07.24 16:29:00'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Still it outputs the same.

Comment: No I am there is no dot format between the year,month and the day. Can you see the format, I am trying achieve. I don't why the format is not according to what I am specifying.

Comment: @JafferWilson - I understand now. No, it is not possible, format of datetimes is always same, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. If need another format, then is necessary convert it to `string`s like `df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @jezrael your output does not match the output given in the question

Comment: @jezrael I tried your way as suggested in the comment but it didn't worked.

Comment: @JafferWilson - Give me a sec, I add comments to answer with samples.

Comment: @JafferWilson - So you want datetimes with custom format? If yes, in python impossible.

Comment: @JafferWilson - Not sure if understand each other. Do you need datetimes (type datetime) with format `YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS` ?

Comment: Yes.. I will try the above suggestion of yours.. give me a moment.